# Can anyone help me identify the plane in this photograph?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

I'd be very grateful for any help in identifying this U.S. plane. Other photos in the album look like they're from WW2.

Comment: could you post more photos on imgur?

Comment: It looks like a Ford Tri-Motor

Comment: Depends on how accurate do you want to detect it and how will you use it?
The simplest way is to build horizontal line filter to identify wings position, build contours, filter out only the biggest and most horizontal ones and then wrap them with the rectangle. This will be the biggest part of the plain, won't it?

Comment: @dmitry.kresin I'm not sure if you're joking but this is my favorite comment of the day.

Comment: Ford trimotor is a High-Wing monoplane, that in mage looks a biplane. A model often mistaken as a Ford is the rare trimotor built by Fokker of The Netherlands, a propaganda movie about the anarchists in Spanish Civil War: 'Aguiluchos de la FAI en tierras de Aragon', shows a Fokker.

Answer (score 48):

What you have there is I believe a Boeing Model 80A-1:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://vintageairphotos.blogspot.com/2013_06_01_archive.html)</sup>

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://www.museumofflight.org/aircraft/boeing-80a-1)</sup>

You can read more about it on [Wikipedia: Boeing Model 80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_80)

The Model 80 air transport aircraft was built in the mid 1920's. It is notable as being the aircraft used for the first flight to feature a flight attendant, which were registered nurses at the time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you partially recognize this off-hand?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes No, I searched google images for "3 engine biplane" then scrolled until the first picture in my answer showed up. The Model 80 showed up sooner, but the early Model 80's did not have a tri-tail design so it threw me off a little bit.